# How pass an Interfaced parameter to Spring4D?

Tags: delphi, dependency-injection, spring4d

I have the following example.
Is there any easier way to pass a Interfaced variable that already registered for Container to resolve it?
Or, is there another way to use this feature?

**that's my interfaces**

```pascal
    IString = interface
      function Value: string;  
    end;  

    IUser = interface
      function Name: IString;
    end;

    ILogin = interface
      function User: IUser;
      function Password: IString;
    end;
```

**the classes implementation**

```pascal
    TString = class(TInterfacedObject, IString)
    private
      FValue: String;
    public
      constructor Create(const AValue: String);
      function Value: String;
    end;

    TUser = class(TInterfacedObject, IUser)
    private
      FName: IString;
    public
      constructor Create(const AName: IString);
      function Name: IString;
    end;

    TLogin = class(TInterfacedObject, ILogin)
    private
      FUser: IUser;
      FPassword: IString;
    public
      constructor Create(const AUser: IUser; const APassword: IString);
      function User: IUser;
      function Password: IString;
    end;
```

**the registration on container**

```pascal
    GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TString>.Implements<IString>;
    GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TUser>.Implements<IUser>;
    GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TLogin>.Implements<ILogin>;
```

**calling**
So when a have to Create these interfaces I calling this way, this's nested parameters made the code complex and exhaust to read (and see)

```pascal
    GlobalContainer.Resolve<ILogin>([
      TValue.From(
        GlobalContainer.Resolve<IUser>([
          TValue.From(
            GlobalContainer.Resolve<IString>(['UserName'])
          )
        ])
      ),
      TValue.From(
        GlobalContainer.Resolve<IString>(['SuperSecretPassword'])
      )
    ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all this smells like the [Service Locator anti pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) - you should rather use a factory.

The current construct requires knowledge about the object graph and passing two different values to the same types. Something a factory is very good for.

So rather than just replacing a ctor call with a resolve call in the consumer code (something you should avoid as much as possible) you can register a factory for your case:

```
type
  ILoginFactory = interface
    [some guid]
    function CreateLogin(const userName, password: string): ILogin;
  end;

  TLoginFactory = class(TInterfacedObject, ILoginFactory)
    function CreateLogin(const username, password: string): ILogin;
  end;

  function TLoginFactory.CreateLogin(const username, password: string): ILogin;
  begin
    // can also inject the container to the factory and use resolve here - 
    // but doing it the pure DI way for now because the graph to create is simple
    Result := TLogin.Create(
      TUser.Create(
        TString.Create(username)),
      TString.Create(password));
  end;
```

This `ILoginFactory` then should be injected into the class that currently has the `GlobalContainer.Resolve` calls. This also helps moving up to the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: Seems like it. but the `username` and the `password` are interfaces and they aren't a primary type.

Comment: In your question they are

Comment: Not directly. `ILogin` receive an `IUser` and `IString` as parameters. `IUser` receive an `IString` to create. And finally `IString` receive a `String` as parameter. And that's the point, I not passing a primary type directy, I'll send it to another `Interface`, and I pass this `Interface`

Comment: Which is what I am doing in the `TLoginFactory` - so what is your point?

Comment: Yes, it is. But when the levels growing. Do I call a factory inside another one?

Comment: I suggest you read up on how to design code DI friendly and where to use which patterns. Using a DI container is not a magic silver bullet if you are missing certain concepts. Mark Seemanns blog and book are good starting references for that. Also it could be the case that you are dealing with "creatables" here that should not be resolved by the container at all (see http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/) but by a dedicated factory. Usually most of the container resolved types are not requiring user input as their ctor dependencies anyway.

Comment: I'll read it. And I found a lot of articles by Nick Hodges those i'll read too. I have started use this framework about a month ago. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make the calls easier.
Maybe I don't doing it the right way. But it make the calls more simple.

I create a **helper class**

```pascal
    TContainerHelper = class helper for TContainer
    public
      ResolveAsTValue<T>: TValue; overload;
      ResolveAsTValue<T>(name: string): TValue; overload;
      ResolveAsTValue<T>(arguments: array of TValue): TValue; overload;
      ResolveAsTValue<T>(name: string;arguments: array of TValue): TValue; overload; 
    end;
```

Now when i need resolve an **Interface** that depend the another one I just:

```pascal
    GlobalContainer.Resolve<ILogin>([
      GlobalContainer.ResolveAsTValue<IUser>([
        GlobalContainer.ResolveAsTValue<IString>(['UserName'])
      ]),
      GlobalContainer.ResolveAsTValue<IString>(['SuperSecretPassword'])
    ]);
```